# Wordpress Form Submit button GETS (or POSTS) form data to external page

Tags: wordpress, get, submit

We have a wordpress website that does marketing display, but now we want to allow a customer to submit an email and selection to a separate website with a landing page that will handle the backend DB work and finish them in the other website.

Something like,
www.ourmarket.com/getdata  (on Submit button click GETS to...) 
www.ouradminsite/landingpage.aspx (which processes the data that the use will not see then...)
www.ouradminsite/login.aspx (where the user can now login)

I am not familiar with WP at all, but I was able to create a page with a form that has the textbox/combobox I need.

I thought it would be something simple, but somehow it seems not.  I read about AJAX and doing something in functions.php and creating a custom .js file, but when working on the marketing site I find no way to add this type of function in.

My fall back is to have the WP page just have a link to a generic landing page where they enter data, but it would be visually jarring to the customer unless I duplicate the WP site for one page.

Is there an easy way to just tell WP to redirect to an external page with a GET?

UPDATE--------------

I like to think I'm making progress.  I found a [link](http://www.0to5blog.com/creative/gravity-forms-submitting-forms-to-3rd-party-applications/) that may have given me a good start.  I added a function to the functions.php file located in my WP theme.  It starts like this:

```
 add_action("gform_post_submission_4", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
 function set_post_content($entry, $form){
 //Gravity Forms has validated the data
 //Our Custom Form Submitted via PHP will go here
 // Lets get the IDs of the relevant fields and prepare an email message
 $message = print_r($entry, true);
 // In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
 $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
 // Send
 mail('myuser@mycompany.com', 'Getting the Gravity Form Field IDs', $message);
**wp_redirect("http://my.hearbuilder.com/hellomoto.aspx",301);**
 }
```

From there I tried to edit the function to do that wp_redirect, just a simple one to start.  This is added under the mail statement:
`wp_redirect("http://my.hearbuilder.com/hellomoto.aspx",301);`

From this [link](http://www.hearbuilder.com/free-trial/), when I fill out the form I can get the email, but the new page did not display.  I added the `exit;` line and still got the same result, the page seems like it hangs.

The end result is that I need to have the new website landing page display (after it processes the data from the Wordpress form.

What am I still missing?

Answer (score 0):

yes use wp_redirect()

```
if($_POST):

  $textbox=$_POST['textboxname'];

  $url= 'url'.'?custom=hello&textbox='.$textbox.'&anothervalue='.$anothervalue;
  wp_redirect($url);
  exit;
endif;
```

you can easily add the variables to the string as needed. The easiest way to control the url properly is to post the information to the same page , catch the post and redirect (place before get_header call or any output has started)

The other way is php Curl which is more difficult esp when dealing with .asp pages, but if you have access to the other server it makes figuring it out easier!

Comment: Okay, but I need to scrap the value in the text box and combobox to go with the redirect (that is what a GET does?).  Normally I'd add an action and method to the form tag, but I'm not understanding where that can be done.  Where does one put your code?

Comment: You could do a form action with the url and the form information will be appended if its a get action. But you lose control of what is in the url, so its better to submit the form to itself using post and then create your url as you want and then redirect.